# Plotting proportion of count to geom_point size

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, proportions

I am using ggplot to create a scatterplot of survey responses between two groups. Currently I have the size of the points based on count of the answers per group. Since the groups' ns are so different, one group is consistently larger than the other. I would like the size of points to be based on what proportion of individuals within each group answered the certain answer choice. My current code and graph out are below:

```
ggplot(data, aes(y = value, x = gain, group = demographic, color = demographic)) +
  geom_count(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

[current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9oNa.png)

My data currently looks like this:

```
structure(list(hispanic = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("hispanic", "non_hispanic"), class = "factor"), 
    gain = c("SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", 
    "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", 
    "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16", "SU_11_15", "SU_11_16"), value = c(5, 
    5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, NA, 5, 4, NA, NA, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, NA, NA, 4, 3, 
    3, NA, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 3, NA, NA, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 3, 
    2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, NA, 3, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1, 5, 3, 5, 
    5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 
    4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
    5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -138L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to obtain the proportion of "value" answers hispanic/non hispanic individuals, respectively, provided. The values range 1-5. I would like to calculate this for each gain, there are 21.

I have unsuccessfully tried to calculate proportions directly into my dataframe, as I have only two columns, but need to find proportions for 21 questions. I have played around with various ggplot tools, like scale_size_area and scale_size_continuous but they are only allowing me to manually inout a range, not change area to proportion of answers.

Comment: We can certainly help you calculate the proportions directly in the data frame, but we'll need some sample data to do it. Please edit your question to include enough sample data to illustrate the problem. `dput()` is the nicest way to create sample data for sharing, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows. It will be copy/pasteable and include all needed information about the data structure.

Comment: @GregorThomas I have included some sample data, thank you for informing me to do so.

Comment: Thanks, the format of the sample data is great, but it seems like it's not sample data that illustrates the problem well because every row of the sample has a different `gain` and the sample only has non-hispanic rows - so there are no proportions to calculate. Could you please share a sample that better illustrates the issue? Maybe share all rows for 2 or 3 gain values, something like `dput(subset(your_data, gain %in% c("SU_11_1", "SU_11_2")))`.

Comment: @GregorThomas Okay I've updated it. Thank you so much for being so helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df_summary = df |>
  count(gain, value, hispanic) |>
  group_by(gain, value) |>
  mutate(
    n_all= sum(n),
    proportion = n / n_all
  ) |>
  ungroup() |>
  rename(demographic = hispanic)
df_summary
# # A tibble: 21 × 6
#    gain     value demographic      n n_all proportion
#    <chr>    <dbl> <fct>        <int> <int>      <dbl>
#  1 SU_11_15     1 hispanic         1     1      1    
#  2 SU_11_15     2 non_hispanic     2     2      1    
#  3 SU_11_15     3 non_hispanic    10    10      1    
#  4 SU_11_15     4 hispanic         7    19      0.368
#  5 SU_11_15     4 non_hispanic    12    19      0.632
#  6 SU_11_15     5 hispanic        12    34      0.353
#  7 SU_11_15     5 non_hispanic    22    34      0.647
#  8 SU_11_15    NA hispanic         2     3      0.667
#  9 SU_11_15    NA non_hispanic     1     3      0.333
# 10 SU_11_16     1 hispanic         1     4      0.25 
# # … with 11 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

ggplot(df_summary, 
       aes(y = value, x = gain, color = demographic, size = proportion)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  labs(size = "Proportion")
```

[image]